# Msg 10300, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

Unable to create Assembly `[System.Web]` in SQL Server 2014.

The Query is given below.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY

[System.Web] from

'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll' with permission_set = UNSAFE
```

Throwing an error

> Msg 10300, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER DATABASE DBName SET TRUSTWORTHY On
use MASTER
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY to public
```

and then Run Command

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY

[System.Web] from

'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll' with permission_set = UNSAFE
```